# Embassy background check

Tags: pre-clearance

Can Regional security officer(work at embassies) ask the host government for privat informations that are only allowed for judge's  and law enforcement agencies about a candidate for a background check ?

Comment: That will depend on treaty arrangements between the two governments and the details might not be public knowledge. Is there some specific embassy & government you have in mind?

Comment: How is this related to travel?

Comment: @Sam What kind of background check and for what purpose?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to travel.

Answer (score 2):

Deciding if the officer can **ask** the host government is probably a question of administrative procedure in the embassy.

Deciding if the host government can **answer** and reveal *usually* secret or confidential information about their citizens is up to the host government and their laws and constitution. **Most nations reserve the right to cooperate with foreign intelligence agencies, and to pass information about their own citizens or third-country citizens.**

What will happen is another question. The [Five Eyes Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes), the NATO, and the EU are routinely cooperating on many intelligence matters, but they are also democracies with laws to safeguard citizen's privacy.